# Finder cannot search some files when OS language is Japanese or Chinese

Tags: macos, finder

Finder cannot search files whose name has format xxx-yyy-1.2.3zzz for example a-x-5.2.txt when input the full name in the search box.
OS version: 11.4
OS language: Japanese or Chinese
By the way, it's correct when OS language is English.

Is it a bug? or this kind of input has special meanings?
[image]

Comment: No, that format doesn't have any special meaning. Please post a screenshot of **System Preferences > Language & Region**?

Comment: I posted a Language& Region screenshot. I cannot make sure whether the screenshot is uploaded successfully in my network environment. Can you see it?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is visible in your question.